# How can I call an API different endpoints by calling my loadApi function every time I need to add a new end point? I'm using axios for my request

Tags: node.js, express, axios, pug, webapi

I'm working with an API and I'd like to know how to send a request to multiple end points by calling my "Load Api " function every time I need to work with a different end point.

Here's my code with some examples to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  let test = await loadData();

  res.render("index", { title: "Home", data: test });
});

// Axios Request to Coin Market Cap Web API
async function loadData(limit) {
  let baseUrl = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/';
  let response = await axios.get( baseUrl + 'v1/cryptocurrency/map', {
    headers: {
      'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': process.env.CMC_PRO_API_KEY,
    },
  });
  // success
  return await response.data;
};
```

On this part   `baseUrl + 'v1/cryptocurrency/map'` I though I'd be able to pass a param to loadData e.g. `endPoint` and concatenate it with base url.

After that, I'd assign an actual end point to the `endPoint` value when calling the function:

```
 let test = await loadData('example/endpoint/abc');
```

Can anyone of you help me with a solution for that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

NVM!
My logic was correct. I was just using an invalid end point/no longer working.

Thanks anyway!